# Why is Mongoid/Moped throwing Timeout::Error to Airbrake in production Rake tasks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, mongoid, airbrake, moped

I'm having a problem on my production installation. I have several scheduled rake tasks that run successfully. However, I've been getting MANY `Timeout::Error: execution expired` emails from Airbrake.

But, here's the weird part: the Rake tasks all complete successfully. I'm capturing the stdout/stderr in the cron command, and the errors don't appear in the logs. I've also added simple print statements to the end of the rake tasks to verify their completion.

How can I further troubleshoot this?

Here is a stacktrace from one of the emails:

```
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/moped-1.2.5/lib/moped/connection.rb:203
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/moped-1.2.5/lib/moped/connection.rb:203
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/moped-1.2.5/lib/moped/connection.rb:235
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/moped-1.2.5/lib/moped/connection.rb:203
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/moped-1.2.5/lib/moped/connection.rb:260
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/moped-1.2.5/lib/moped/connection.rb:260
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/moped-1.2.5/lib/moped/connection.rb:259
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/moped-1.2.5/lib/moped/connection.rb:153
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/moped-1.2.5/lib/moped/connection.rb:30
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/moped-1.2.5/lib/moped/node.rb:507
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/moped-1.2.5/lib/moped/node.rb:122
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/moped-1.2.5/lib/moped/node.rb:527
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/moped-1.2.5/lib/moped/node.rb:542
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/moped-1.2.5/lib/moped/node.rb:526
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/moped-1.2.5/lib/moped/node.rb:515
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/newrelic_moped-0.0.3/lib/newrelic_moped/instrumentation.rb:24
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.4.2.1/lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:242
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/newrelic_moped-0.0.3/lib/newrelic_moped/instrumentation.rb:20
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/moped-1.2.5/lib/moped/node.rb:70
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/moped-1.2.5/lib/moped/node.rb:376
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/moped-1.2.5/lib/moped/cluster.rb:112
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/moped-1.2.5/lib/moped/cluster.rb:125
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/moped-1.2.5/lib/moped/cluster.rb:125
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/moped-1.2.5/lib/moped/cluster.rb:78
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/moped-1.2.5/lib/moped/cluster.rb:147
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/moped-1.2.5/lib/moped/session/context.rb:108
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/moped-1.2.5/lib/moped/session/context.rb:50
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/moped-1.2.5/lib/moped/database.rb:76
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/moped-1.2.5/lib/moped/query.rb:36
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/mongoid-3.0.5/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:69
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/mongoid-3.0.5/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:18
[PROJECT_ROOT]/lib/tasks/reminders.rake:7
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33
[GEM_ROOT]/bin/rake:19
[GEM_ROOT]/bin/rake:19
```

Comment: yo Ben! could you give me more info so I can replicate more easily?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what info you're looking for. I'm using Mongoid 3.0.5, Rails 3.2.8, Ruby 1.9.3, MongoDB 2.2.0

Comment: Hi, we've been seeing alot of the same.  We've been working with our MongoDB provider to figure it out, but no major luck so far.

Two clues:
(1) The problems started when we switched to a replica set layout
(2) When our replica set went down temporarily, we started getting the tons of the exact same error rather than Mongoid dealing with the RS downtime gracefully.

Comment: I'm using a replica set as well. I'd love to hear of any progress you make! I'll be updating this post if I find anything.